# Windows 10 requires certificate confirmation everytime the certificate is used

Tags: windows-10, certificate, popups

I have to press "OK" everytime I authenticate to a server using particular certificate on win10. It is used by within a msoftware, but the software provider told me that it is caused by the OS. How do I prevent this annoying popup?

[image: The pop-up image]

**Translation:**

- Potvrdit Certifikát = **Confirm certificate**
- Lokalita gtw-ssl-ws01.sukl.cz vyžaduje vaše přihlašovací údaje = **Locality
  gtw-ssl-ws01.sukl.cz requires your login information:**
- Vystavitel = **Issuer**
- Platný od: = **Valid from:**

Comment: The certificate is in the users "personal" certificate store. Do you think that exporting and importing it into root trusted certificates would prevent the "Confirm certificate" pop up?

Comment: Sorry, I pressed Enter instead of Shift+Enter when getting more translations. Now the original post has the translations.

Answer (score 0):

This is an optional feature activated when importing the certificate. If you can, try first exporting the cert (**with** its private key) to a PKCS#12 file, deleting it from Personal, and re-importing back to Personal *without* selecting the additional "protection" features.

Comment: the PKCS#12 export option is greyed out, only Binary X.509, X.509 and PKCS#7 are available

Comment: Yes, I am an admin on that machine and I am in charge of the PCs on the domain.

Comment: I guess you are suggesting that it might be greyed out because I am logged in as an user without admin privileges, right?

Comment: No, more likely because the certificate's private key was set to non-exportable (or because it's in a smartcard maybe?)

Comment: Probably made that mistake (along with checking the extra protection featuers) a long time ago when I installed that certficate as non-exportable. I will try to obtain the cert again and install it "without he additional protection features".